# .NET force windows application to display only english numbers

Tags: .net, numbers, cultureinfo

I am building a culture specific .net windows application and recently i faced a problem with the number shape which is changing according to the OS culture. I want to just use the English shape for all cultures especially the Arabic one.

regards,

Comment: Do you want English format regardless of OS culture? If so, question title contradicts. If you want Arabic format for numbers then question body says something else!

Comment: what i want is to display numbers in english shape, not any other shpae

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Globalization CultureInfo class, then force your program to use the US English culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You can learn a bit more about it on [this MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se513yha%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't force numbers to be shown in english shape whem i change the windows regional settings to for example (Arabic - Saudi Arabia).